# What is the meaning of a number changing process?

Tags: cosmology, dark-matter

On my lecturer's notes on *Dark Matter* I am told:

*"It is customary to define densities normalised by the time dependent volume $V (t) = a(t)^3$. The reason for this is that, in the absence of number changing processes, the comoving number density remains constant with time evolution."*

**I don't understand what is meant by a number changing process.**

The image is given as an example of the preservation of the comoving number density.

Initially I thought a number changing process was one in which the number of the particles changed as the process evolved but I believe the image is trying to emphasise that the number of particles is kept constant. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The number of particles does not change, but the volume increases as $V(t) = V_0 a^3(t)$, because of expansion. 
Naively one can compute the number density as
$$
n(t) = \frac{N(t)}{V(t)}=\frac{N_0}{V_0 a^3(t)},
$$
where I used the fact that $N(t)=N_0$ in the absence of process that change the number of particles.

However, if we spice up things by normalizing the volume by the expansion factor $a^3(t)$ in the previous expression, we have 
$$
\hat{n}(t) = \frac{N_0}{V_0 a^3(t)/a^3(t)}= \frac{N_0}{V_0},
$$
which is indeed the definition of *comoving number density* and it is manifestly time-independent.